# Connecting to Arduino Ethernet Shield

Tags: shields, ethernet

How do I figure out how to connect to my arduino using ethernet shield?

It prints the IP in the serial monitor, but it doesn't work, and adding the port doesn't make a difference.

The client example works, so it's not broken or anything.

I'm using `Arduino 1.6.5` IDE on a `Mega 2560`. I'm trying to run the `Examples/Ethernet/WebServer` example.

Comment: Please state which Arduino you have. Also which version of the IDE. You need to run one of the "server" examples, please state which example you are trying.

Comment: @NickGammon Like this?

Comment: What IP address are you using? What are you typing into your web browser? What do you see in the Serial Monitor?

Comment: @NickGammon That's in the original post: "It prints the IP in the serial monitor, but it doesn't work, and adding the port doesn't make a difference." Meaning I take the printed ip. using ip:port doesn't work either.

Comment: `It prints the IP in the serial monitor` - I'm not asking you to *describe* what you see. Please copy and paste it. What IP addresses are you using on your local LAN? For example, do you see a message like "new client"?

Comment: @NickGammon well, I meant to imply that I tried this IP and "it doesn't work". My browser gives me a 'timed out' message. I don't really know how to connect to it locally (or rather, how to find that IP) but I'm connecting to the same switch as the arduino

Answer (score 1):

Your question is kind of trivial, but from what I understood you're typing the IP address (that the Arduino displays on the serial monitor)  into your browser.

First, make sure you connect your Ethernet shield to your router using an ethernet cable. (Now it's connected locally...)

Second, even if you type in your Arduino's IP address into the browser, the browser will return nothing because the Arduino simply has nothing to display, and hasn't been programmed to accept requests.

To actually have the Arduino display something you can try the Webserver example sketch or you can follow this great [Tutorial](http://startingelectronics.org/tutorials/arduino/ethernet-shield-web-server-tutorial/) that I found very useful for beginners.

BTW ports are only used to expose your Arduino to the Internet, in other words if you don't portforward to your Arduino, your Arduino won't be able to get requests from outside your local network (Wi-Fi,Ethernet).

Comment: Like I stated in the question, I'm using the webserver example sketch. I also portforwarded my arduino.

Comment: I think it would be more accurate to say that ports are used to identify the service running on the Arduino (for example to differentiate between HTTP and NTP). Port forwarding happens on the router and makes a service running on an internal host (at a private IP address such as 192.168.0.42 or 10.0.4.2) visible from the "outside world" (the WAN interface).